# How to send data to server through JSON

Tags: android, json, http-post

I 'm completely new to JSON.I have learned how to get data from server through JSON.I 'am trying to create a registration activity and trying to send data as entered by the user.

the registration has following feeds:

1.Name

2.College name

3.Mobile no.

4.email ID

i want to send data in the following format:

```
{
"register": [
                {
                 "username": "abcd",
                 "college name": "kkddge",
                 "email": "example@gmail.com",
                 "Mobile no.": "1234567890",
                  }
          ]
    }
```

I have tried a code like this from a video i saw in youtube.I don know what's actually happening here:

My `ServiceHandler.java` file.

```
    package com.defcomdevs.invento16;


    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
   import java.util.List;
   import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
  import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
  import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
   import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
  import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
  import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
  import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
  import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
  import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.Toast;

 public class ServiceHandler {

static InputStream inputStream=null;
static String response=null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public ServiceHandler(){

}

public String makeServiceCall (String url ,int method){
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method);
}

public String makeServiceCall (String url, int method ,List<NameValuePair> params){

    try{

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity =null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;


        if(method == POST){
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            if (params!=null){
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        }else if (method==GET){

            if(params!= null){
                String paramString=URLEncodedUtils.format(params,"utf-8");
                url += "?" +paramString;
            }

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse= httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        }

        httpEntity=httpResponse.getEntity();
        inputStream=httpEntity.getContent();

    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException c){
        c.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"),8);

        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine())!=null){

            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Buffer Error","Error:" + e.toString());
    }

    return response;
 }
 }
```

Code part that calls the servicehandler

```
    private class InventoRegistration extends AsyncTask{



    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        //Toast.makeText(context,"Entered doInBackGround",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        List<NameValuePair> postparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name",username));
        postparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("College",usercollege));
        postparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Mobile no.",usermobile));
        postparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email",useremail));

        ServiceHandler serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler();
        String json = serviceHandler.makeServiceCall(url,ServiceHandler.POST,postparams);

        if (json!=null){
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                boolean error= jsonObject.getBoolean("error");
                //checking if error node in JSON

                if(!error){

                    //new Category created
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Registered Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                else{
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Registration Unsuccessfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }catch (JSONException j){
                j.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else{
            Log.e("JSON data","JSON data error");
        }
        return null;
    }
    }
```

My server side script file `inventoRegister.php`

```
   <?php
   include_once './DbConnect.php';
    function createNewPrediction() {
     $response = array();
    $Name = $_POST["Name"];
    $College = $_POST["College"];
    $Mobile = $_POST["Mobile no."];
    $Email = $_POST["Email"];
            $db = new DbConnect();
   // mysql query
    $query = "INSERT INTO Register(Name,College,Mobile,Email) VALUES('$Name','$College','$Mobile','$Email')";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if ($result) {
        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["message"] = " added successfully!";
    } else {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Failed to add!";
    }
     // echo json response
    echo json_encode($response);
   }
    createNewPrediction();
    ?>
```

this code is not working.As the data is not shown.and there is no response.I have given the response as a toast you can see.But no toast is displayed too.

the url is my server url which is a server on my local pc.I have checked the connection and all it is correct.

url i 'm using here is :`http://<my server address>/inventoRegister.php`.Is this the write way of server address?Any help with code will be thankful.

My DbConnect.php file:

```
    <?php
    class DbConnect {  
    private $conn;        
    function __construct() {        
    // connecting to database
    $this->connect();
    }        
    function __destruct() {        
    $this->close();
    }        
    function connect() {        
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . './Config.php';                  
    $this->conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());         
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die(mysql_error());        
    // returing connection resource
    return $this->conn;
    }        
     // Close function          
    function close() {
    // close db connection
    mysql_close($this->conn);
    }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: i googled it.and that's how i found this code. I want to know whats wrong with this code

Comment: show the code of the server page your requesting, as it should process the input you send then return a response

Comment: I have added the code for my server page.I 'm new to server scripting this is a code i referred from net.Hope this is the one that you are requesting.

Comment: the values in ur Database are they all strings?

Answer (score 1):

BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"),8);

```
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine())!=null){

        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }

    inputStream.close();
```

instead of writing these chunk of lines you can use a simple method

String line =EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()) this will convert your response to string.

place this line below client.execute method and below  this write logcat.verbose statement.

Comment: Yes sir it says: ` Unknown MySQL server host 'DB_HOST' (110)
11-05 20:51:27.243 13821-13912/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=18: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415afbc0)'

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed

Comment: you have specfied your host incorrectly.  what value you assigned in db host variable

Comment: define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); this the line in the config.php file.localhost is the name the server.I 'm using a lamp server in my ubuntu laptop.and have setup phpMyadmin in it.

Comment: i used 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost now it keeps on doing the doInBackground process and never quits.

Answer (score 0):

Which backend you are using to send your data to the server php or servlet jsp ?. If you want to send you should wrap your data in to a array list with data type namevalue pair. But before that pls tell me  which backend you are using .

Comment: I have edited my question please have a look.Thanks.

Comment: And i 'm not getting any feedback from the server , i have used toast inside my code.But there is no message displayed.

Comment: why you didn't write code for get request in php it may be possible that you are executing get request and since you haven't write code for get request in php it is returning nothing. Just print the line variable value using logcat.

Comment: By request code do you mean code for connecting to data base? if yes then i have one i will post it here.

Comment: `print the line variable value using logcat.`- i don't know how to do this.

Comment: NO i am not talking about this. I want to say that in your php code you have written $_post for getting the values sent by your app. The $_post variable fetch value only if you are making post request from your app. But in case if you are sending parameters from your android app using get method yhen must use $_get in your php code .

Comment: No sir i 'm using post method

          if(method == POST){
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            if (params!=null){
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

Comment: Logcat.verbose("response",line);

Comment: i have found out the error it says:
  `11-05 19:35:30.690 12900-12941/? E/Buffer Error: Error:java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
11-05 19:35:30.690 12900-12941/? E/JSON data: JSON data error`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94342/discussion-between-midhun-and-developer-vaibhav).

Comment: ok try this one write $_REQUEST in place of $_POST and run your app  and see what is returns.

Comment: still the same i think it is something about `UnsupportedEncodingException`

Comment: you cannot display toast inside doInBackground method

Comment: I have set table Collation as `utf-8_bin` for all varChars is that a problem

Comment: inventoRegister.php in this  above include_once statement  write echo "hello"; exit(); try this and see what it returns .

Answer (score 0):

Note that if the column type is not nvarchar the value should be without these ' '
for example if the column mobile is of type int then it should be written like this:

```
$Mobile not '$Mobile'
```

like this:

```
"INSERT INTO Register(Name,College,Mobile,Email) VALUES('$Name','$College',$Mobile,'$Email')"
```

Answer (score 0):

And one more thing you cannot display toast inside the doInBackground method. because doInBackground method runs in the background and toast deals with the ui thread . So put your toast statement outside the doInBackground or inside the onPostExecute method.